# Call Function After Event Listener Completes - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to call a function in Javascript when an `EventListener` has completed running any attached code? I am using an external library with an `EventListener`, which performs a specific action when the Listener is called. I need to run my function after the external library's code finishes running.

I'm asking for a sort of `EventListener` that I can place on an `EventListener` to see when an `EventListener` has completed its task.

I cannot take the source code and put it in my file, and I cannot directly place my function call at the end of the external library's `EventListenerHandler` in their code. I also do not initiate the `Event` or the `EventListener`, so I don't think I can place a callback function on it (I'm still new to Javascript, so maybe, I'm not entirely sure). The event does not use AJAX.

`EventListener` --> `EventListener` --> `Event`

How can this be done?

[image]

Here is a picture of my EventListeners. In my specific case, I want to execute the following piece of code after the External Library catches the `Event` with the `has_many_add:after` `EventListener`, and finishes running the code in the associated Handler :

```
$('select.user_select').select2({
  minimumInputLength: 2
})
```

The external library performs a callback when the button is clicked:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.button.has_many_add', function(e) {
  var before_add, fieldset, html, index, parent, regex;
  e.preventDefault();
  parent = $(this).closest('.has_many_container');
  parent.trigger(before_add = $.Event('has_many_add:before'), [parent]);
  if (!before_add.isDefaultPrevented()) {
    index = parent.data('has_many_index') || parent.children('fieldset').length - 1;
    parent.data({
      has_many_index: ++index
    });
    regex = new RegExp($(this).data('placeholder'), 'g');
    html = $(this).data('html').replace(regex, index);
    fieldset = $(html).insertBefore(this);
    recompute_positions(parent);
    return parent.trigger('has_many_add:after', [fieldset, parent]);
  }
});
```

I can't change this code, and I need my function to go after this call to `has_many_add:after` `EventListener`. I tried using the following:

```
$(".button has_many_add").click(function(){
  $('select.user_select').select2({
    minimumInputLength: 2
  });
});
```

However, this code seems to execute before the external library's event handlers do.

Comment: it would be helpful if you say which 3rd party library are you using.

Comment: The ActiveAdmin Gem for a RubyOnRails Application, but the functionality for this particular part of the Gem is written in Javascript.

Comment: You should distil your problem down to a piece of code pasted here. It's pretty impossible to help otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your external library doesn't stop the event from bubbling you should be able to do this:

```
$(document).on('has_many_add:after', function(){
    //do your stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a really common thing, especially in jQuery. Most jQuery functions actually support this through callbacks.

Here's an example:

```
$(document).on('click', 'div', function() {
    console.log("a div got clicked, so naturally we're running cool stuff when it completes");
});
```

In that example, the console.log and everything between those callback braces will run only when a div is clicked on your document.

You can also define a function outside of this listener, then call it from inside when the callback is triggered:

```
function myFunction (){ 
    console.log("doing more stuff after the event listener is triggered"); 
});

$(document).on('click', 'div', function() {
    console.log("a div got clicked, so naturally we're running cool stuff when it completes");
    myFunction(); // invokes our other function
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't think I can add a callback to my code, because it seems that the external library's code runs first. I also can't add a call to my function at the end of the external library's code. Please see the information added to my question for more details.

Comment: You could probably wrap it in a custom event: [CustomEvent doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent)