# JavaScript: Add Event Listener to an Event Listener

Tags: javascript, event-handling, chart.js

I am working with ChartJS. I have a `onClick` function defined for the chart which changes the data for the chart and calls an `update()` function. It looks like the chart does not actually fully update until the `onClick` function has finished, so there is not way for me to access the new data in the chart in the `onClick` handler.

I am hoping there is a way to add an event handler on that `onClick` event handler, but I can't figure out how to do it. I tried adding a separate `onClick` event handler, but it looks like they run asynchronously, and I can't figure out a way to guarantee that the `onClick` event handler that is changing and updating the chart finishes first. Ideally, I would be able to create an event handler on the chart's event handler, but I don't know how to do that.

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31864143/call-function-after-event-listener-completes-javascript/31864472) asked some years back, but it looks like they might have been able to add an event handler to their event handler because it was a custom event, and wasn't just 'click'. Does anyone know of a good solution to this?

```
function chartOnClickHandler(e) {
    if (e.native.detail !== 2) return;     // if not double click return
    if (e.native.target.style.cursor === 'default') {
        handleDoubleClickAddPoint(e);
    }
    else if (e.native.target.style.cursor === 'grab'){
        handleDoubleClickRemovePoint(e);
}

} // I want to run code here, after chartOnClickHandler has finished executing. 

// Below is my second event listener. Ideally, I could call the passed in function 
// whenever chartOnClickHandler is called. 
chartElement.addEventListener('chartOnClickHandler', (e) => {
    // Handle event

});
```

Comment: is this something that can be solved with promises?

Comment: I feel like there is something missing from this question. Is the reason you need something to happen later because you have just updated the chart? And what did you update it with? ChartJS has other event you can listen for...like when the chart updates. So just listen for the chart update after the click and get your info there.

Comment: Regarding promises, I'm not sure. I'm pretty new to this. I can't solve this using callbacks, so I assumed promises also wouldn't apply here. But I am really new to this.

Rob, yes, I update the chart, and then I need the updated data points. When I run the update function, it doesn't seem to update the datapoints until the onClick event finishes. I think that the other events you mention could definitely work. I'm trying to look through the documentation to see if I can find one that listens for an update. I'll update if I find it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @RobLouie, Which event listener are you referring to? I'm looking at the list of event listeners in chrome, but can't find an 'onUpdate' one. I also can't seem to find anything on the ChartJS website that has an event like that.

Comment: Ya chart.js animation is all over the place kind of. You could possibly use onAnimationComplete, which finishes after the chart animates, which it presumably does after the data is updated. https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.8.0/configuration/animations.html

Comment: My other question I guess though is where do you get that other data? You theoretically have access to it somehow right? That's the bigger missing part for me. You can always get a little hacky and use setTimeout to call another function later as well, but it really depends what data access you need. Without knowing that its a little hard to know the exact answer.

Comment: I wish I saw your comment about the setTimeout earlier. That's what I ended up going with, though I am using queueMicrotask instead. It does seem a little hacky, but I can't find a better way. And yes, I understand your point. The reason I don't have access to the data that I want is because I want the exact pixel location of a point on the chart after I have inserted it into the chart's data array. I am letting ChartJS place the point on the chart to do the calculation for the exact pixel coords for me.

Comment: Update: I actually have to wait for the animation of the chart to fully finish, otherwise, the pixel coordinates aren't updated correctly. It looks like if I try to get the pixel coordinates during the middle of the animation, it actually will return the coordinates during the middle of the animation. So the only way to do what I want to do is with a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

99% chance this doesn't work so please someone kindly correct it so it works. Also I feel like this is not even on the right track.

```
function chartOnClickHandler(e) {
    return new Promise((res, rej)=>{
        if (e.native.detail !== 2) rej(0); // arbitrary reject value
        if (e.native.target.style.cursor === 'default') {
            res(handleDoubleClickAddPoint(e));
        }
        else if (e.native.target.style.cursor === 'grab'){
            res(handleDoubleClickRemovePoint(e));
        }
    })
}

function handleSynchronously(e) {
    chartOnClickHandler(e).then(
        // do synchronous stuff here
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this! Unfortunately, I'm not sure if this will work, because if I pass handleSynchronously as the onClick handler, the Chart will not update until that function completes. I need a way to run another completely separate function after the onClick finishes.

Comment: @jc_a Im waiting for a pro to improve or demolish my answer. Would adding `chart.update()` work when you want the `chart` object updated?

Comment: I actually do have a `chart.update()` in the `handleDoubleClickAddPoint()` function. For some reason, it doesn't seem to update the actual chart until after the `onClick` function finishes.

Comment: My intent was that `chartOnClickHandler` will run, then using `.then()` chaining you can get something else to run after the chart gets updated. Is this what you refer to by `onClick`? Then for event listener you add `handleSynchronously` instead

Comment: I think the code you made would have worked with some slight modifications, but I think I found an even simpler solution: `queueMicrotask( () => { /* Code here */ } )` or `setTimeout(() => { /* Code here */ }, 0)` both seem to work. I think what this is doing is just jumping to the next event in the event queue, and once that is done, comes back to the function you create in either queueMicrotask or setTimeout. This is the best solution for me because I can basically grab both states; the chart before `update()` and the chart after `update()`, both of which I need.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a simple way around my issue. Instead of adding an event listener that waits for the function to finish, I found a way to mess around with the event queue. Using either `queueMicrotask()` or `setTimeout()`, I am able to add a function to the event queue that comes after the current running event.

Update: I ended up going with `setTimeout(function, 1000)` because I have to wait for the Chart's animation to end to properly get the data I need.

```
function chartOnClickHandler(e) {
    if (e.native.detail !== 2) return;     // if not double click return
    if (e.native.target.style.cursor === 'default') {
        handleDoubleClickAddPoint(e);
    }
    else if (e.native.target.style.cursor === 'grab'){
        handleDoubleClickRemovePoint(e);
    }

    queueMicrotask( () => { 
        // Function to be run after the current task/event (chartOnClickHandler)
    });

    setTimeout( () => { 
        // Function to be run after the current task/event (chartOnClickHandler)
    }, 0);     // timeout can be 0, since we don't care about delay time, just to push the event down in the event queue.

} // Queued function will run here, after chartOnClickHandler has finished executing. 


// Below event handler is not needed and can be removed. 
chartElement.addEventListener('chartOnClickHandler', (e) => {
    // This event handler is not needed anymore
});
```

Comment: `setTimeout` is a workaround as opposed to a direct solution such as promises. However, I don't even know if my code works so I'm glad you found something that that does.